# WebApi: property that is collection of complex objects is alwasy empty

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return this class in web api:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        var fruits = new Category("Fruits");
        var veggies = new Category("Veggies");

        var apple = new Product("apple");
        apple.Categories = new List<Category>() { fruits };

        var potato = new Product("Potatoes");
        potato.Categories = new List<Category>() { veggies };

        var banana = new Product("Banana");
        banana.Categories = new List<Category>() { fruits };

        List<Product> list = new List<Product>(){
          apple, potato, banana
        };

        return list; 
    }
```

For whatever reason the Categories collection is always returned empty...
Am I missing something ?

Thanks!

Update:

```
 public class Category
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Category() { }

        public Category(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                throw new ArgumentException("name must be set");

            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Aaand.. It won't show the categories because both properties in Category class don't have public setter.

Makes me wonder why serializer is checking for access modifier of setter.

Comment: did you check by adding breakpoint if the value for categories are present ? And I am not sure what `new List<Category>() { fruits };` does please post the constructor of category class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category class had 2 properties, both having private setter; properties with private setter won't be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that the private set issue have been fixed in web api RTM release.